# How do you mask a react-native <View /> with any shape?

Tags: react-native

It seems that all components in react-native are rectangles or rounded-rectangles (which can also represent a circle).

How do you mask a `<View />` with an arbitrary shape like a hexagon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came to the conclusion that this feature isn't available out of the box, so I implemented a native component in Objective-C called **[react-native-masked-view](https://github.com/gilbox/react-native-masked-view)**.

The [basic idea](https://github.com/gilbox/react-native-masked-view/blob/master/react-native-masked-view/RNMaskedView/RNMaskedView.m#L18) is to use the `mask` property of the UIView class:

```
CALayer *mask = [CALayer layer];
mask.contents = (id)[_maskUIImage CGImage];
mask.frame = self.bounds; //TODO custom: CGRectMake(left, top, width, height);
self.layer.mask = mask;
self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

and it works something like this in JavaScript:

```
<MaskedView maskImage="mask.png">
   ...
</MaskedView>
```

Comment: If I want to create a rhombus shaped view without adding an image how can I implement it?

Comment: This https://github.com/gilbox/react-native-masked-view component is already deprecated, anyone knows any working component? I badly need this kind of feature.

Comment: The solution isn't working any more. It is for old version of react native.